# Groovy issue "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException"

Tags: java, groovy, geb

Recently I am facing the below issue with one of my job executions.

Below is the exception msg:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager.clearResolutionCache() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at script1677201791728558065883.run_closure1$_closure3(script1677201791728558065883.groovy:20)
    at script1677201791728558065883.run_closure1$_closure3(script1677201791728558065883.groovy)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse_closure5(ConfigSlurper.groovy:242)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:80)
    at script1677201791728558065883.run_closure1(script1677201791728558065883.groovy:16)
    at script1677201791728558065883.run_closure1(script1677201791728558065883.groovy)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse_closure5(ConfigSlurper.groovy:225)
    at script1677201791728558065883.run(script1677201791728558065883.groovy:14)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse_closure5(ConfigSlurper.groovy:270)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:288)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:162)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:151)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:303)
```

It is working previously. Now my scripts are running but only 40% of them are running.
and few are failing with

> classMethod FAILED
> geb.error.UnableToLoadException: Unable to load configuration @ 'file:/C:/Users//B2B-AUTO/QA1/build/resources/test/GebConfig.groovy' (with environment: chrome)
> at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:293)

How to fix this issue. let me know if you need more detail. please share your thoughts

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: The error message indicates that the version of `io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager` that you are using does not have a no-arg method named `clearResolutionCache`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call a method from a newer version of the library.  `clearResolutionCache()` does NOT exist in versions prior to 4.0.0, and given the package name you posted it seems like you are on version 3.8.1 or earlier.

It looks like ChromeDriverManager is in a different package than the one you listed.  Here is the latest API:

https://javadoc.io/static/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/5.2.3/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/managers/ChromeDriverManager.html

Notice the package is:

io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager

You have:

io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager

Here are the docs from 3.8.1 and you can see `clearResolutionCache` does not exist:

https://javadoc.io/doc/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.8.1/index.html

If you want to use `clearResolutionCache()` you'll have to upgrade your driver to 4.0.0+

Comment: Yes, it seems to have changed between 3.x and 4.x, because in [3.8.1](https://javadoc.io/static/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.8.1/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/ChromeDriverManager.html) it is still in the old package. You can also see that in the source code when e.g. switching between release tags 3.8.1 and 4.0.0 in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager).

Comment: @kriegaex Yep thanks for pointing that out.  I was bothered by the fact it said MissingMethodException and not ClassNotFoundException, and you pinpointed it.

Comment: Thank you. let me try the updated version